# Another way to change the color of a checkbox's text

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2015 with an ASP.Net front end.

I've got this line of code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkMedical" runat="server" Text="Medical" ForeColor="White" 
              Font-Size="X-Small" Visible="False" />
```

When I run this code, the text "Medical" is black.

Why isn't it white?  Is there another way to change the text color?

Comment: Have you tried to use a browser inspector to see if a CSS class might be overriding your setting or you might have some javascript changing the color?  BTW, you have Visible = "False".  Why is this visible in any color?  Again, some javascript?

Comment: ^ this. I just tested your code and it works fine (changed visible to true obv). Pretty sure there is a generic css class overriding your color, or some javascript code changing it.

Comment: The visibility gets changed based on certain criteria from the back end (C#).  But I'm going to check the inspector and see if that leads me to anything.

Comment: Use developer tools to identify what is overriding the inline-css generated by the ASP Control's ForeColor attribute. Regardless, you could save a headache by trying the code I suggested in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Colors should be set by CSS and not C# content generation. You can technically use your code, and it should work, but something may be overriding the inline-css colors. Try adding a CssClass to your element as such:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkMedical" CssClass="chkMedical" runat="server" Text="Medical" ForeColor="White" 
          Font-Size="X-Small" Visible="False" />
```

Then add some CSS to your page as such:

```
<style>.chkMedical { color: #FFF !important; } </style>
```

You should probably add the  tags in the head of the document, or at least new the top or bottom of the .aspx page, your choice. Or you could of course add this to a CSS file that is referenced by your document.

Note that although you can use the element ID instead of a class, ASP.NET generally appends the ContentPlaceHolderID to non-static ASP controls on your page. So if we assume that your ContentPlaceHolderID is called "ContentPlaceHolder1" then the code below could also work.  Since the ContentPlaceHolder may change, or someone may change your ASP Control to static (causing the element ID to change) I recommend the use of a class to avoid the potential headache (personal experience).

```
<style>#ContentPlaceHolder1_chkMedical { color: #FFF !important; } </style>
```

Comment: OP - are you still having issues? Was this able to resolve your problems?